# Correct the wrong matches words to fix moving files in folders properly

Tags: powershell

I use a script to make folders and move files to relative folders sorted by year.

I have a list of *film + year* in this format:

```
rambo (1982)
rambo III (1988)
Independence Day (1996)
...
```

I expect this structure:

```
├─1982 [folder]
│ ├─Rambo.torrent [file]
│ ├─Rambo DVD.torrent [file]
│ └─Blade Runner.torrent [file]
├─1985 [folder]
│ └─Rambo: First Blood Part II.torrent [file]
├─1988 [folder]
│ └─Rambo III.torrent [file]
├─2008 [folder]
│ └─John Rambo.torrent [file]
:
```

But this is how the structure actually looks like:

```
├─2008 [folder]
│ ├─Rambo.torrent [file]
│ ├─Rambo: First Blood Part II.torrent [file]
│ ├─Rambo III.torrent
│ └─John Rambo.torrent
:
```

Script creates the folder correctly and also moves the files but does so in its own way.

My script wrongly moving every .torrent *with same word* in the name of the file like `Rambo` in the same year folder.

**SCRIPT**

```
$movies = @()
(Get-Content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_) {
  $properties = @{
    date = $_.Substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1, 4)
    name = $_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf("("))
  }
  Write-Host $date
  Write-Host $name

  $movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$torrentFiles = dir $torrentPath

foreach ($movie in $movies) {
  $datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
  if (-not(Test-Path $datePath)) {
    New-Item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
  }
  $words = ($movie.Name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1 }
  $significant = $words.Count
  $torrentFile | Move-Item {
    $matchingWords = 0
    foreach ($word in $words) {
      if ($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word) {
        $matchingWords += 1
      }
    }
    if ($matchingWords -ge $significant) {
      $_ | Move-Item -Destination $datePath
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Kob, welcome to stackoverflow.   I don't see a question in your post, and the format of this site  is questions and answers.  The nature of your code, and data files makes it hard for anyone but you to debug.   Do you understand how to set breakpoints and examine variables in the ISE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `BaseName` property of the file to match the movies in the list and after the first run you could adopt your list and add the movies that aren't moved. Thats probably more reliable then matching words.

So after some refactorings, your script could look like this:

```
$movieFile = 'C:\Path\Test4.txt'
$moviesDestionation = 'C:\Destination'
$moviesSource = 'C:\Path'

# parse movie list
$movies = Get-Content $movieFile | ForEach-Object {
        $regMatch = [regex]::Match($_, '(?<name>.*?)\s?\((?<year>\d+)\)$')
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $regMatch.Groups['name'].Value
            Year = $regMatch.Groups['year'].Value
        }
    }

# create folder structure
$movies | select -Unique Year | ForEach-Object { 
    md (Join-Path $moviesDestionation $_.Year)  -Force -ea 0
}

# move all files
(Get-ChildItem $moviesSource -Filter '*.torrent') | ForEach-Object {
    $matchedMovie = $movies | where Name -eq $_.BaseName 
    if ($matchedMovie)
    {
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path $moviesDestionation $matchedMovie.Year)
    }
}
```

---

**Regex used:**

```
(?<name>.*?)\s?\((?<date>\d+)\)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Powerful solution but files like `Cose da pazzi (2)` , 
`C era una volta il West - 720p` , 
`C Era Una Volta In America 1080p (2)` , 
`Code Name: Geronimo [HD] (2012)` , 
`Cocoon – L’energia dell’Universo (1985)` , are not matched because there is 
punctuation and and there are also numbers that have nothing to do with the year of the film like 720p, 1080p (not from 1900-2016). Can you fix your regex to 'bypass' some 
punctuation like _ ' : , please ?

Comment: The regex should be fine, check this: https://regex101.com/r/xG3tP5/1 . I also was able to read the file list in PowerShell (except the one which is missing the year which you probably want to fix).

Comment: mmm.. something is missing because script match these file names but not move torrent files inside folders because names between torrent files and within in text list has some little difference. Look short list here, please http://pastebin.com/Rhs8XY4M. For example, in file list I have `C’era una volta in america [HD] (1984)` and I have torrent 3 torrent files `C era una volta in America (2).torrent` , `C Era Una Volta In America 1080p (2).torrent` ,`C Era Una Volta In America (2).torrent` BUT these 3 files are not moved inside `1984` folder. **ErrorPowershell** http://i.imgur.com/CGcoXp5.png

Comment: **Every** file you showed me have something **you** have to fix. Like the movie list usually doesn't contains the file extension, but Cose da Pazzi (2).torrent` suddenly does. `C’era una volta in america ` contains  `HD` inside the movie file list but not within the filename. Same with the other examples. While you can adopt the script to prevent these failures, I would just fix the movie list.

Comment: I wrong to write, sorry. Cose da Pazzi (2) has not extension but I wrong to paste. Movie list is here http://pastebin.com/zmg1PfVD i choose letter C like example, torrent file name list is here http://pastebin.com/RnXFp1U3. I have more torrent files of file name list inside text because there are some torrent duplicates that are like `name (720p).torrent` or `name (2).torrent` because are different version of same movie

Comment: are you find a fix, Martin ?